# What is a good algorithm for pitch shifting?

Tags: web-audio-api, webassembly, pitch-shifting, audio-worklet

I have an algorithm in place that works for audio files, but I'm trying to apply it to frames to achieve an auto tune type of effect. It shifts the pitch but makes it sound broken up or like it's skipping when I apply it to the individual frames from an audioworklet. [This](https://sites.google.com/site/mikescoderama/pitch-shifting) is essentially the algorithm in c#. I converted it to typescript to use it with WebAssembly. I'm at a loss as to why the output sounds great on a full audio file, but broken up or like it's skipping when I apply it to individual frames. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check this one https://github.com/olvb/phaze ?

Comment: I did. That was my original go to. It does work very well. My only issue with it is that I'm trying to apply this functionality to multiple tracks at once, so they all need their own instance of it. After about 5-10 tracks it starts to, I guess the best way to describe it is that it breaks. So, I started experimenting with WebAssembly. I have gotten ok results, but not good enough. I guess I could try converting this logic into WASM.

Comment: Hi @user2961688 ! Have you found anything interesting since ? Do you play your tracks/stems directly from Web Audio API or using a player lib ?